# How to get variable value from MdDialog to base component in angular 2?

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu

I am working in angular 2.
I have two components one is for my form and another is for my dialog box & when I have click on button present in form I will get a dialog box which hold the check boxes and return the value of checked check boxes in a variable.
Now my question is that I want to access variable of dialog component in form component.

**1. motor-cycle-package.component.ts**

```
moterCyclePackages = 
    [ { "name": "P1", "value":"P1", "price": "20","state": false}, 
    { "name": "P2", "value":"P2", "price": "30", "state": false}, 
    { "name": "P3", "value":"P3", "price": "40", "state": false} 
]; 
constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<MotorCyclePackageComponent>) { }
```

**2. form.service.ts**

```
 constructor(private http: Http, private dialog: MdDialog) { }
 public motorCyclePackage(): Observable<boolean>{
     let motorCycleRef: MdDialogRef<MotorCyclePackageComponent>;
     motorCycleRef = this.dialog.open(MotorCyclePackageComponent);
     console.log(motorCycleRef);
     return motorCycleRef.afterClosed();
 }
```

**3. user-form.Component.ts**

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private formservice:formService){}
public motorCyclePackage() 
{
    this.formservice
        .motorCyclePackage()
        .subscribe(res => this.result = res);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- suppose you wanna access this property `moterCyclePackages`, you can do something like this: `componentInstance`

**2. form.service.ts**

```
public motorCyclePackage(): Observable<boolean>{
    let motorCycleRef: MdDialogRef<MotorCyclePackageComponent>;
    motorCycleRef = this.dialog.open(MotorCyclePackageComponent);
    console.log(motorCycleRef.componentInstance.moterCyclePackages); // this one
    return motorCycleRef.afterClosed();
}
```

- if you wanna get data back when modal close, you can put data to close method

**1. motor-cycle-package.component.ts**

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<MotorCyclePackageComponent>) { }
closeDialog() {
  this.dialogRef.close(any data you need);
}
```

**3. user-form.Component.ts**

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private formservice:formService){}
public motorCyclePackage() 
{
    this.formservice
        .motorCyclePackage()
        .subscribe(res => this.result = res);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have done this but I want this data only when I have click ok/submit button on dialog.

Comment: With this code the data will automatically load when we open the dialog box.

Comment: when click ok/submit button, send data back in `dialogRef.close()` method

Comment: Can you please tell me how to console " this.dialogRef.close(any data you need); " value in this function into user-form.component.ts

Comment: you already did that in `3. user-form.Component.ts`, `res` is `any data you need`